# How to build multiple targets from one makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to parameterize my makefile targets. Currently, it has a

```
TARGET = main
```

declaration near the top. It derives the `SRC` list from that as well as does lots of other things.

I've changed my C code though, so that I have multiple different top level .c files to basically get variant builds. So what I want to be able to do is basically do

```
make target1
```

or

```
make target2
```

And vary what `TARGET` is set to in the makefile. I'm confused how to accomplish this. I thought I might add something like

```
target1: all
    TARGET=target1
```

This didn't seem to work too well at all though. Is there a general pattern for how one does this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Parameterized variable names and target-specific variables may do what you want, as the value of a target-specific variable is normally "inherited" by the prereqs of that target (assuming you are using GNU make):

```
target1_SRC=123 456
target2_SRC=abc def

target1: TARGET=target1
target2: TARGET=target2

target1: all
target2: all

all: ; @echo $($(TARGET)_SRC)
```

Then you can run `make target1` or `make target2`, for example:

```
$ make target1
123 456
$ make target2
abc def
```

Answer (score 21):

I would suggest simply spelling out your targets as separate targets in the makefile:

```
all: target1 target2

OTHER_OBJS = misca.o miscb.o miscc.o

target1: target1.o $(OTHER_OBJS)

target2: target2.o $(OTHER_OBJS)
```

Then `make`, `make target1`, `make target2`, and so on will all do what you want.

You say your makefile "derives the `SRC` list from [`$(TARGET)`]" in some presumably high-tech way, but it might be interesting to try explicitly listing the object files in a low-tech way instead, as above.  Using different *make* targets is arguably Make's general pattern for producing different results.

Comment: This in incredible, but where is `all:` documented? I see first use of it in the example in [section 4.3 of the GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types), but no discussion.

Comment: It's fairly ordinary really… By default, Make rebuilds the first target listed (see [GNU Make §9.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Goals) for example), and `all` is the conventional name for that target.

Answer (score 3):

Well... Using pmake we can do this: (If use gmake we can replace $(.THINGS) for equivalanet $@ $< and so...

```
.PHONY: clean run

PROGRAMS = progrname_one progrname_two... and so

all: $(PROGRAMS)

$(PROGRAMS): $(PROGRAM=$(.TARGET))

CC = clang -I.

CFLAGS = -O0 -g -std=gnu11 

OBJS = 

LIBS = 

CPATH = .

$(PROGRAM): $(PROGRAM).c $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(.TARGET) $(.IMPSRC) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) 

$(PROGRAM).o: $(PROGRAM).c

clean:
    rm -f *~
    rm -f *.core
    rm -f $(PROGRAMS) $(PROGRAMS).o

run:
    ./$(PROGRAM)

dbg:
    lldb ./$(PROGRAM)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Eric Melskis comment, if you wanted also have your 'make all' functionality make both programs, then perhaps this would be a good substitute:

```
target1_SRC=123 456
target2_SRC=abc def

all: target1 target2

target1: TARGET=target1
target2: TARGET=target2

target1: ; @echo $($(TARGET)_SRC)
target2: ; @echo $($(TARGET)_SRC)
```

Here I also added the default rule to have both targets made by default.