# Using gnu make with a makefile, why is my .o file not deleted?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I have a simple makefile that works correctly with gnu make, except the object file named 'txt.o' is not removed, using 'rm tst.o'. Here is the text from the makefile.

```
# Make 'PPCBIN' variable set to folder that has the C library and binary files used
# to compile to the correct target.
PPCBIN = /binary_folder_here

CC = $(PPCBIN)/gcc
CFLAGS = -O3 -mpowerpc -Wa,-m603
LDFLAGS = -g
tst : tst.o
    ${CC} ${LDFLAGS} -o tst tst.o
tst.o : tst.c
    ${CC} -c ${CFLAGS} $< -o $@
# remove the temporary output file, 'tst.o'.
clean:
    rm tst.o
```

Anyone know why the rm command here is not removing the 'tst.o' file?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Probably because you didn't type `make clean`. If you type `make`, the first target is made (`tst` in this case). [This SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919505/how-to-build-multiple-targets-from-one-makefile) may be interesting for you.

Comment: You want to keep the .o files around otherwise you'll be rebuilding everything from scratch each time.

Comment: Thanks Michael, make clean works correctly. I will read the gnu manual a little more Good point Chris about keeping the .o files. I'll probably manually delete the ones that need rebuilding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What command did you enter for the `make`?

If you just enter `make`, it will choose the first target it finds. In this case, that target is `tst`:

```
tst : tst.o
    ${CC} ${LDFLAGS} -o tst tst.o
```

The make will proceed according to the dependencies, so it will also make the target `tst.o` if `tst` is not up to date with it.

Your removal is the target `clean` which, the way your makefile is structured, won't be executed unless you enter:

```
make clean
```

If you want it to clean up after the build, include it in your target. One way you can do this is by creating a new target that makes and cleans. Make this your first target:

```
build_all: tst clean
```

Now, `make` or `make build_all` will build the `tst` target then do `clean`.

However, as was pointed out in the comments, there are good reasons to keep your `.o` file around (*e.g.*, not causing it to be rebuilt every time when not necessary).

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably use this option (build_all:) at some point.