# How to write a macro to make cross-platform compile easier?

Tags: c, compilation, macros, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I am writing a `C` program and my operating system is `MacOS`. 
I am wondering how to add a macro in order to compile my `C` program under different operating system, mainly `Windows` and `Linux`?

Thanks a lot for providing me an idea on this question.

Comment: Whats the macro supposed to do?

Comment: It very much depends on what system-dependent things your program is relying upon.

Comment: Why not to create different blocks in your makefile according to your target? passing the target as additional information, in this topic it is well explained:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make and different targets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919505/how-to-build-multiple-targets-from-one-makefile

Comment: I wouldn't use macros but an OS abstraction layer. Then it's easy to switch between MacOS, WindowsOs and LinuxOS when compiling.

Comment: As @4386427 says - you should **design** to be portable.  Separate out the portable and non-portable code.  Put the OS dependant code into a separate set of functions and compile into a DLL/.so file.  It takes much more work initially but saves a huge amount of effort in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
    #define OS_NAME "windows"
    /* add your windows specific codes here */
#elif defined(__linux__)
    #define OS_NAME "linux" 
    /* add your Linux specific codes here */
#elif defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
   #define OS_NAME "MacOS"
   /* add your Mac specific codes here */
```